# SQL NVL on multiple tables columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to show result of SAL column, such that if they have monthly SAL then show, if not show as of today daily SAL. Our Monthly SAL is 35 days behind, so we wanted to show something like nvl(monthly,daily). Tried following and stuck on how to write NVL on top of these two queries

```
SELECT nvl(MNTH_SAL,DAILY_SAL) FROM(

SELECT sum(currsal)DAILY_SAL 
FROM SAL_DAILY WHERE
SAL_DATE=TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'YYYYMMDD')--SAL_DATE HAVE DATES LIKE 20200504
and EMP_ID='123' 

SELECT  sum(MSAL) MNTH_SAL
FROM SALY_MONTH
   WHERE 
     AND SAL_MDATE=  TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate),'YYYYMM') ---SAL_MDATE HAVE DATES LIKE 202005
      and EMP_ID ='123'

)
```

see samples here we pick from last available **daily SAL details**,as monthly doesnt have that date yet?

```
daily       
SAL_DATE    EMP_ID  DSAL
20200501    123 273.21
20200502    123 2284021.99
20200503    123 21476932.57
20200504    123 22743859.69

monthly         
SAL_DATE    EMP_ID  MSAL
202004  123 34495.59
202004  123 1036951.62
202004  123 2086.69
202004  123 5429296.83

output for current month        
date    emp_id  sal
202005  123 46505087.46
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  update with samples input/output data

Answer (score 0):

With your current approach, you'll need to wrap those `select` statements with parenthesis.

```
SELECT NVL((SELECT sum(currsal)
            FROM SAL_DAILY 
            WHERE SAL_DATE=TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'YYYYMMDD') --SAL_DATE HAVE DATES LIKE 20200504
            AND EMP_ID='1234'), 
            (SELECT sum(MSAL)
             FROM SALY_MONTH
             WHERE SAL_MDATE=TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate),'YYYYMM') ---SAL_MDATE HAVE DATES LIKE 202005
             AND EMP_ID ='1234'))
FROM DUAL;
```

Although an ideal approach would be to `union` those two tables using relevant columns and perform conditional aggregation.

Comment: @stackuser Try now. This gets you the output you would have gotten had your attempt worked. Your sample output looks different  from what your script intended.

Comment: no luck this isnt working working missing expression error.

Comment: @stackuser Do those two select run separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a `UNION` of the two queries, with the `monthly` query first, and then select just the first row from the result

```
SELECT "date", emp_id, sal
FROM (
  SELECT 0 AS rnk, 
         TO_CHAR(SAL_DATE) AS "date",
         emp_id,
         SUM(MSAL) AS sal
  FROM SALY_MONTH
  WHERE SAL_DATE = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMM')
    AND EMP_ID = 123
  GROUP BY SAL_DATE, EMP_ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,
         SUBSTR(SAL_DATE, 1, 6),
         emp_id,
         SUM(dsal)
  FROM SAL_DAILY
  WHERE SAL_DATE = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD')
    AND EMP_ID = 123
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(SAL_DATE, 1, 6), EMP_ID
  ORDER BY rnk
) s
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Output for your sample data:

```
date    EMP_ID  SAL
202005  123     22743859.69
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdf69/28)

Note that this gives a different result to your expected output, which sums all the daily salaries for May even though the query in your question only looks at the day before today. If you *do* want to sum all the daily salaries for May, change this line:

```
WHERE SAL_DATE = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

to

```
WHERE SUBSTR(SAL_DATE, 1, 6) = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM')
```

And you will get:

```
date    EMP_ID  SAL
202005  123     46505087.46
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdf69/34)

Comment: looking at his expected output he wanted sum(SAL_DAILY), the result should be 46505087.46

Comment: @sunnybabau yeah - OP's expected output is not the same as their query can possibly produce... But I've made an edit to show how to get that expected output